# Google Protobuf3 Multiple string in message issue

Tags: c++, networking, protocol-buffers

I have a message that looks like:

```
message Connected {
  sint32 xloc   = 1; // x spawn world position
  sint32 yloc   = 2; // y spawn world position
  sint32 zrot   = 3; // z spawn rotation
  string sector = 4; // sector name (unsure about this)
  string name   = 5; // player name
  string pid    = 6; // player id
  string scolor = 7; // ship color
  string sname  = 8; // ship name
}
```

I am attempting to initialize it within my c++ code like this:

```
server::player::Connected connectMessage; // send this to this joining client
connectMessage.set_name("clientName");
connectMessage.set_pid("clientId");
connectMessage.set_scolor("shipColor");
connectMessage.set_sname("shipName");
connectMessage.set_xloc(0);
connectMessage.set_yloc(0);
connectMessage.set_zrot(0);
```

For some reason as I set my string parameters, the prior strings before it gets set to that string value. So, if I do the set_pid the name field will also change to the pid. set_scolor the name & pid will be set to the s_color. set_sname the name, pid & scolor will change to be the sname. It seems like they are all sharing the same string pointer field location.

The result of each of the string fields will be "shipName" after execution.

Am I not initializing my message correctly? Or do I need to do something differently here? When I Serialize my messages from a coded stream I get my expected message, but manual creation doesn't seem to be working with what I'm currently trying to do.

Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: What is `stats` actually? You're missing to give us enough information to diagnose your problem. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Stats is a structure of data, unfortunately that isn't the problem. I could do:
server::player::Connected connectMessage;
connectMessage.set_name("clientName");
connectMessage.set_pid("clientId");
connectMessage.set_scolor("shipColor");
connectMessage.set_sname("shipName");
connectMessage.set_xloc(0);
connectMessage.set_yloc(0);
connectMessage.set_zrot(0);

and the resulting string of each string in the Connect message would be "shipName" at the end of the execution.

Comment: [Add additional information](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39928885/edit) to your question please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to use a repeated field for my strings seems to have fixed the problem.

```
message Connected {
  sint32 xloc = 1; // x spawn world position
  sint32 yloc = 2; // y spawn world position
  sint32 zrot = 3; // z spawn rotation
  // [0] => username
  // [1] => userid
  // [2] => shipcolor
  // [3] => shipname
  repeated string userinfo = 4;
}
```

With this I am able to manually add the new strings to the repeated string list.

```
server::player::Connected connectMessage;
connectMessage.set_xloc(stats.m_xPos);
connectMessage.set_yloc(stats.m_yPos);
connectMessage.set_zrot(stats.m_zRot);
// [0] => username
connectMessage.add_userinfo();
connectMessage.set_userinfo(0, stats.m_clientName);
// [1] => userid
connectMessage.add_userinfo();
connectMessage.set_userinfo(1, stats.m_clientId);
// [2] => shipcolor
connectMessage.add_userinfo();
connectMessage.set_userinfo(2, stats.m_shipColor);
// [3] => shipname
connectMessage.add_userinfo();
connectMessage.set_userinfo(3, stats.m_shipName);
```

It definitely allows for a cleaner .proto file, but it's strange that just using individual strings was causing a problem.

Comment: I faced the same problem... when i create a proto object, all the string inside seem to share the same address.